# Recovering corrupted VB.NET Form file?

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery

Good day. This question is directly related to this one I made here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911099/there-is-no-editor-available-for-form1-vb-error

There, I was working on my VB.NET 2010 Express application, I saved, then a blackout came and now, apparently, I can't view the designer nor code of my Form file (Form1.vb).

On StackOverflow, I was recommended to check for the From1.vb file, and try to open it on Notepad. If nothing appeared, it would mean that my file was corrupted.

I open it on Notepad, and I get a blank file. It is 27kb, but it only has blank spaces. So I assume it is corrupted.

I was told this place was better for dealing with corrupted files, about techniques to recover them.

I use Windows7, VB.NET 2010 Express.
I run Windows7 on Parallels Desktop, Mac OS X. However, I do not believe that is the problem, most likely it was that damned blackout... this is the first time that happens to me. VB.NET worked just fine for me all time (about a month and half).

Thank you.

Comment: Given that your file is not deleted - I'm not sure if it's possible to recover them. Try the programs mentioned over [here](http://superuser.com/questions/101805/how-to-recover-files-from-a-broken-usb-flash-drive) and the linked questions

Comment: You've probably already solved this problem by rewriting the code, but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940757/c-project-lost-anyways-to-recover-it) on Stack Overflow just reminded me of an alternative way of going about your problem. You can download Reflector now (while it's still free) and recover most of your code (minus the comments) from any compiled binaries you may have lying around. It won't get you everything, but it might be better than nothing.

Comment: Thanks, I will check that out. And no, I have not written everything back.. it was a bit of a big project, all in a single Form.vb file, haha........ damn. Thank you.